# Will vs would. Reason behind answer

Tags: will-would

**Which of the following is a grammatically CORRECT sentence?**

A) You had better told her everything, or else you will lose a friend.

B) You had better told her everything, or else you would lose a friend.

***C) You had better tell her everything, or else you will lose a friend.***

D) You better had tell her everything, or else you will lose a friend.

E) You better had tell her everything, or else you would lose a friend.

So, the answer here is (C). I don't understand why *WILL* is right and *WOULD* is wrong. Explain please.

Also, why is *HAD BETTER TOLD* wrong?

Edit - Wow, the more I'm reading into it. The more everything sounds right. What the hell?

Comment: A, B, D, and E all sound incorrect by the time you reach the first comma.  They all have mixed tenses.  For A and B - "You had better" is looking to the future while "told" is in the past.  For D and E - "had" is in the past while "tell" isn't.  C is the only answer where the entire sentence has a matching tense.

Comment: Yes; here, 'You had better told her…' will always be wrong.

Comment: Before I fall into setting out Answers that aren't justified by the Question, why have you shown no research but merely demanded Answers?

Answer (score 2):

"Had better", despite the "had", is not a perfect, and cannot be followed by a past participle. It must be followed by the base form of the verb.

(Don't try to analyse "had better" grammatically: it's a frozen form with obsolete grammar).

The reason for *will* rather than *would* is that this is not hypothetical: think of *had better* as the same as *should* or *ought to*. *You will lose a friend* is a prediction of what **will** happen if you don't tell her everything, not a hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

"had better told" is wrong because it uses two different tenses in a single phrase: "had better" implies future action, whereas "told" is past tense. Likewise "would" is not concrete when used in future tense. When talking about the future, "would" means a willingness to do something or a hypothetical, as opposed to "will", which is a prediction or statement that something is definitely going to happen.